# Unexpected UICollectionView layout inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a table cell which consists of UICollectionView + some other items :

```
import UIKit

class PhotosTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var navigationHandler : PhotoNavigationHandler?

    private let photoWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/4
    
    private let titleLabelView : UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)
        view.textColor = .black
        view.text = "Photos"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var buttonView : UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
        view.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "arrow.right"), for: .normal)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGaleryClickedHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
        return view
    }()
    
    @objc private func goToGaleryClickedHandler() {
        guard let handler = navigationHandler else {
            return
        }
        
        handler()
    }
    
    private lazy var photosPreview : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.register(PhotoGaleryShortCollectionViewCell.self,
                      forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: PhotoGaleryShortCollectionViewCell.self))
        view.dataSource = self
        view.delegate = self
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
        
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }

    private func setupViews()
    {
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabelView)
        contentView.addSubview(buttonView)
        contentView.addSubview(photosPreview)
        
        let constraints = [
            titleLabelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
            titleLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            buttonView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabelView.centerYAnchor),
            buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo : contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            buttonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            photosPreview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabelView.leadingAnchor),
            photosPreview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo : titleLabelView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
            photosPreview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant : photoWidth),
            photosPreview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo : contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            photosPreview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

}


extension PhotosTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell =
            photosPreview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
                                                String(describing: PhotoGaleryShortCollectionViewCell.self),
                                              for: indexPath) as! PhotoGaleryShortCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}

extension PhotosTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: photoWidth, height: photoWidth)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }    
}
```

And here is a collection view cell implementation :

```
import UIKit

class PhotoGaleryShortCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private let area : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(area)
        
        let constraints = [
            area.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            area.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            area.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            area.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

As far as I understand I should get 2 squares placed side by side inside collection view area.

But I get [image]

What am doing wrong here?

Comment: you can set main view width 100% and inner 4 square width to 25% respectively, ignore to use constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because you're setting the cell size, try to remove this part of your code and it will be resolved

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: photoWidth, height: photoWidth)
}
```

also replace this line

```
photosPreview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant : photoWidth),
```

with this one:

```
        photosPreview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant : contentView.frame.height),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it really works...but how can I set the desired size of cell for collection view ?

Comment: Why does the cell size setting break the layout here?

Comment: the problem is with the way you're implementing the whole thing, is it always 2 squares? or it maybe more?

Comment: yes, 2 squares..but they are just placeholders, it could be any ui item for sure

Comment: what do you mean under “the whole thing” ? could you please point me out where I am wrong and what is the right way to implement this ?

Comment: rather than using a collectionView for those 2 squares you can just create 2 Views and put them in StackView, that will be easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set Layout `layout` before you apply it and set your size there, here is some example code:

```
    lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: photoWidth, height: photoWidth)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    return layout
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the layout I had to put the following line here :

```
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

Although it look like a dirty hack but it works. If anyone could explain this...